# OpenCV - view pixel values like Matlab on MouseOver

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv, mouseover

I have been looking around in vain to find a utility in OpenCV that works like the image viewer of Matlab, not fully functional as matlab, but atleast shows pixel values with zoom in/out functionality.

Any guidance/directions/links much appreciated

Thanks

Wajih

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the functionality you want is already available, if you build opencv using qt.
See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html) for an example image, and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/luigidr/installing-opencv-231-with-qt) for details on how to build opencv with qt.

Comment: Just download the sources and build opencv on visual studio ;-) The link I posted gives all the details

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension to MS-Visual studio called [Image Watch](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_image_watch/windows_visual_studio_image_watch.html). It enables you to see the images in debug window during runtime.

You can see the image as well as the values by moving the mouse over the pixels.