# opencv imshow show only the image

Tags: c++, opencv

I've switched from Ubuntu to Windows for my opencv project and while displaying an image using the `imshow` function the image is displayed but the other details like **x axis** and **y axis** information and the intensity values were not shown in the window.

The same code under the Ubuntu build works perfectly. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    cv::Mat imgrgb = imread("C:\\Users\\Len\\Documents\\project\\Images\\1-11.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    // Check that the image read is a 3 channels image and not empty
    CV_Assert(imgrgb.channels() == 3);
    if (imgrgb.empty()) {
        cout << "Image is empty. Specify correct path" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::cvtColor(imgrgb, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    namedWindow("Test", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Test", imgrgb);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

So, how can I display the intensity values along with the current x and y axis information?

Comment: What do you mean? The code you provided is meant to only show the image.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yeah along with the image, in the bottom area it will show the current mouse position x and y along with the intensity value. That's the one I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linux system, but there is no such functionality for OpenCV under Windows.

Comment: No, there is. That worked on my previous build.

Comment: I think I got the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14235435/2277817). Let me try that I will tell you if that works.